# Pause Menu won't activate when I hit escape

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, keycode, pause

I've just started teaching myself coding, and I've been watching Brackey's tutorial series. I'm trying to create a Pause menu, and I've followed along with the video, but for some reason I can't get the menu to activate when I hit escape. I've double checked the code and it should be working, when compared to what's on screen. Is there something I'm missing?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PauseMenu : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static bool isGamePaused = false;

    public GameObject pauseMenu;

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
        {
            if (isGamePaused)
            {
                ResumeGame();
            }
            else 
            {
                PauseGame();
            }
        }
    }
    void ResumeGame()
    {
        pauseMenu.SetActive(false);
        Time.timeScale = 1f;
        isGamePaused = false;
    }

    void PauseGame()
    {
        pauseMenu.SetActive(true);
        Time.timeScale = 0f;
        isGamePaused = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you set the pauseMenu object?

Comment: If the object you are using is a Panel and it is not childed to  Canvas, it will not render. Make sure the object is childed properly then it should be fine. Aside from that, are you getting any errors?

Comment: No it's childed to the canvas, and I'm not getting any error messages. I've done everything Brakeys did in the tutorial up to this point and it just won't work right.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JivuXdrIHK0

Comment: Well, the code looks correct and I can not spot any obvious issues with it. Would you mind posting a screenshot of your current hierarchy? Possibly also have the Canvas component shown to see if it is a scalar issue. Does the UI look correct when enabled before hitting play?

Comment: Sure, https://imgur.com/a/PYX8XFy The UI looks fine before I hit play, but if I start the game with the pauseMenu layer enabled it launches with it open already. hitting escape seems to close it if I do that but not the other way around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that I can see the relevant code and hierarchy I believe I see the issue. In your script, you are checking for input in the `Update()` which is only called when the GameObject the script component is on is active in the hierarchy.

When you are toggling your pause, you are activating and deactivating the GameObject that you assign in the inspector. As the object you assigned in the GameObject that has the script, the `Update()` will never be called after it is disabled.

You have a few options, but the easiest one would be to drag in the reference of the panel `pauseMenu` as the reference object to toggle in your script instead of the `Canvas` object you currently have. That way the `Canvas` can act as a manager for the `pauseMenu`, toggling it when the input changes.

Comment: That did it! Thanks for the assistance,